# The diameter of a convex hull.

Tags: geometry, convex-hulls

I want to prove the following statement:

> Given $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ let $C(A)$ be its convex hull. Prove that $\text{diam }(A)=\text{diam }(C(A))$.

I can suppose that $A$ is a bounded closed set and I know that if $x,y\in A$ are such that $d(x,y)=\text{diam }(A)$ then $x,y\in \partial A$. I tried proving that if $z,w\in \partial C(A)$ then $d(z,w)\leq d(x,y)$ but it is a little difficult to me using the fact $C(A)$ is the convex hull.

Any hint?

Comment: Which formal definition of convex hull are you using? The intersection of all convex sets that contain $A$? Or a different definition? When you are trying to prove intuitive statements like this one, you have to rely on rigorous definitions.

Comment: The convex hull of A is the intersection of all convex sets that contain A. Equivalently, the convex hull of A is the set of all convex combinations of a finite number of elements in A.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\ell = \mathrm{diam}\;A$.

Since $C(A) \supseteq A$, it is trivial to see $\mathrm{diam}\;C(A) \ge \ell$.

If $\mathrm{diam}\;C(A) > \ell$, then one can find $p, q \in C(A)$ such that
$d(p,q) > \ell$.

By [Carathéodory's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carath%C3%A9odory%27s_theorem_%28convex_hull%29), we can express $p$ as a convex linear combination of $P \le n+1$ points from $A$. More precisely, there exists
$$\begin{cases}
p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_P \in A\\
\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_{P} \ge 0
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ with }\quad
\begin{cases}
\lambda_1 + \lambda_2 + \cdots + \lambda_P = 1\\
\lambda_1 p_1 + \lambda_2 p_2 + \cdots + \lambda_P p_P = p
\end{cases}
$$
Similarly, we can find $Q \le n + 1$ points in $A$ such that
$$
\begin{cases}
q_1, q_2, \ldots, q_Q \in A\\
\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots, \mu_Q \ge 0
\end{cases}
\quad\text{ such that }\quad
\begin{cases}
\mu_1 + \mu_2 + \cdots + \mu_Q = 1\\
\mu_1 q_1 + \mu_2 q_2 + \cdots + \mu_Q q_Q = q
\end{cases}
$$
Notice as a function of $p$ and $q$, the distance $d(p,q) = |p-q|$ is a convex function in both of its arguments. This implies

$$d(p,q) = d\left(\sum_{i=1}^P \lambda_i p_i, \sum_{j=1}^Q \mu_j q_j \right)
\le \sum_{i=1}^P\sum_{j=1}^Q \lambda_i \mu_j d(p_i, q_j) \le \left(\sum_{i=1}^P\lambda_i\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^Q \mu_j\right) \ell = \ell$$

Contradicts with our choice of $p, q$ which satisfy $d(p,q) > \ell$. This implies the underlying assumption $\mathrm{diam}\;C(A) > \ell$ is invalid. As a result, $\mathrm{diam}\;C(A) = \ell = \mathrm{diam}\;A$.

**Note**

If one adopt the definition that by convex hull, one mean the collection of all convex linear combinations of points from a set. We don't need Carathéodory's theorem at all. The argument above works as long as $P, Q$ exist and are finite.

Comment: This proof, though correct, is a typical example of unnecessary proof by contradiction, in the form "To prove X, assume not X. Then (without using the assumption not X) prove X. This contradicts the assumption not X. Therefore X." In the present example, you could delete the sentence about assuming diam$((C(A))>l$ and getting $p$ and $q$. Work with arbitrary $p,q\in C(A)$ and deduce (as in your answer) that $d(p,q)\leq l$. That implies diam$(C(A))\leq l$; since you already have the reverse inequality, the proof is complete.

Comment: Does the same argument hold for any normed linear space?

Answer (score 1):

Using the finite-dimensionness in proving this fact is not a good practice since this claim is true in the infinite dimensional case too. Here is a proof:

Let $B$ be bounded subset of a Banach space $X.$ Its obvious that $\operatorname{diam}(B) \leq \operatorname{diam}(\operatorname{conv}B),$ since $B \subset \operatorname{conv}B.$ For the converse, pick $c_1 = \lambda_1 a_1 +(1-\lambda_1) a_2 \in \operatorname{conv}B$ and $c_2 = \lambda_2 b_1 + (1-\lambda_2) b_2 \in \operatorname{conv} B,$ for $\lambda_i \in [0,1]$ and $a_i, b_i \in B.$ Then
\begin{align*}
||c_1 - c_2 || &= || \lambda_1 a_1 +(1-\lambda_1)a_2 - (\lambda_1 c_2 +(1-\lambda_1 )c_2)||=||\lambda_1(a_1 - c_2)+(1-\lambda_1)(a_2-c_2)|| \\
&\leq \lambda_1 ||a_1-c_2||+(1-\lambda_1)||a_2-c_2|| \\
&\leq \operatorname{max}\{||a_1-c_2||,||a_2-c_2||\}.
\end{align*}
If $\operatorname{max}\{||a_1-c_2||,||a_2-c_2||=||a_1-c_2||,$ then
\begin{align*}
||a_1-c_2||&=||(\lambda_2 a_1 +(1-\lambda_2) a_1) - \lambda_2 b_1 -(1-\lambda_2) b_2|| =||\lambda_2 (a_1 - b_1)+(1-\lambda_2)(a_1-b_2)|| \\
&\leq \operatorname{max}\{||a_1-b_1||,||a_1-b_2||\} \leq \operatorname{diam} B.
\end{align*}
Thus $||c_1-c_2|| \leq \operatorname{diam} B,$ meaning $\operatorname{diam} B$ is one upper bound of $\{||c_1-c_2|| : c_1,c_2 \in \operatorname{conv} B\}$ and so it's  greater or equal than its supremum $\operatorname{diam}(\operatorname{conv} B)\leq\operatorname{diam}(B).$ Following the equality $\operatorname{diam}(\operatorname{conv} B)=\operatorname{diam}(B).$

Comment: I'm not sure every $c_1 \in \mathrm{conv}(B)$ can be expressed as a combination of \textbf{two} points $a_1$, $a_2$. Am I missing something in your proof?

Answer (score -2):

Let $x,y\in C(A)$. Then by Carathéodory's theorem, there exists $p,q\le n+1$ and $x_1,\dots,x_{p},y_1,\dots,y_{q}\in A$ such that $x=\sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda_{i}x_{i} $, $y=\sum_{j=1}^{q}\gamma_{j}y_{j}$, $\sum_{j=1}^{q}\gamma_{j}=1=\sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda_{i}$ and $\lambda_{i}\ge0\ (i=1,\dots,p)$, $\gamma_{j}\ge0\ (j=1,\dots,q)$. Therefore

$$\|x-y\| = \left\|\sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda_{i}x_{i}-y\right\|=\left\|\sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda_{i}(x_{i}-y)\right\|\le\sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda_{i}\|x_{i}-y\| \\ = \sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda_{i}\left\|x_{i}-\sum_{j=1}^{q}\gamma_{j}y_{j}\right\| = \sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda_{i}\left\|\sum_{j=1}^{q}\gamma_{j}(x_{i}-y_{j})\right\| \le \sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda_{i}\sum_{j=1}^{q}\gamma_{j}‖x_{i}-y_{j}‖ \le \left(\sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda_{i}\right)\left(\sum_{j=1}^{q}\gamma_{j}\right) \operatorname{diam}A = \operatorname{diam}A\text.\tag1\label1$$

Now by taking supremum over $x,y\in C(A)$, from \eqref{1} we obtain $\operatorname{diam}{C(A)}\le\operatorname{diam}A$. Since $A\subseteq C(A)$ we get $\operatorname{diam}{C(A)}\ge\operatorname{diam}A$. Consequently, $\operatorname{diam}{C(A)}=\operatorname{diam}A$.

Comment: To render the math use Mathjax. You have a tuto here and a quick refrence https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score -2):

Let $x,y\in C\left( A\right) $. Then by Carath'{e}odory's theorem, there
exists $p,q\leq n+1$ and $x_{1},...,x_{p},y_{1},...y_{q}\in A$\ such that $%
x=\sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda _{i}x_{i}$ , $y=\sum_{j=1}^{q}\gamma
_{j}y_{j},\sum_{j=1}^{q}\gamma _{j}=1=\sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda _{i}$ and $%
\lambda _{i}\geq 0,i=1,...,p,\gamma _{j}\geq 0,j=1,...,q.$ Therefore
\begin{eqnarray}
\left \Vert x-y\right \Vert  &=&\left \Vert \sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda
_{i}x_{i}-y\right \Vert =\left \Vert \sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda _{i}\left(
x_{i}-y\right) \right \Vert \leq \sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda _{i}\left \Vert \left(
x_{i}-y\right) \right \Vert   \label{1} \\
&\leq &\sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda _{i}\left \Vert \left( x_{i}-y\right)
\right \Vert =\sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda _{i}\left \Vert \left(
x_{i}-\sum_{j=1}^{q}\gamma _{j}y_{j}\right) \right \Vert   \nonumber \\
&\leq &\left( \sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda _{i}\right) \left( \sum_{j=1}^{q}\gamma
_{j}\right) \left \Vert \left( x_{i}-y_{j}\right) \right \Vert \leq \left(
\sum_{i=1}^{p}\lambda _{i}\right) \left( \sum_{j=1}^{q}\gamma _{j}\right) 
\limfunc{diam}A  \nonumber \\
&=&\limfunc{diam}A.  \nonumber
\end{eqnarray}%
Now by taking supremum over $x,y\in C\left( A\right) $, from (\ref{1}) we
obtain $\limfunc{diam}C\left( A\right) \leq \limfunc{diam}A$. Since $%
A\subset C\left( A\right) $ we get $\limfunc{diam}C\left( A\right) \geq 
\limfunc{diam}A$. Consequently, $\limfunc{diam}C\left( A\right) =\limfunc{%
diam}A$.